# Choosing a Server For my game

Tags: tcp

I'm about to release a MMORPG. In my game, every 1 second, each player sends 30 TCP messages and gets back from the server 30. Every message is not really long. Like 20~ chars.

the point is that I never got my hands with multiplayer games. I have programmed all the server and client, but I don't know what server I'm gonna need. I mean, RAM, CPU, etc... I still don't know what to be ready for, but let's say for 15K same-time clients. As said, every 1 second every client need to get and send 30 TCP messages, and in the most cases I need also to update my non-SQL DB with the data.

Update: It's a multiplayer game, I must have 30 msgs/sec. Most of the msgs are for the current position of the player. Also I'm using C++.

Comment: does the client have a stable TCP-connection with server or it connects each time when it needs to send a message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what your (already implemented) server requires. You'll never know until you try some particular hardware. Rent a powerful dedicated server for a month and profile your game server. At least just check CPU usage. You'll need multithreaded asynchronous networking.

Details you provided help only to calculate how much bandwidth you need:
[~94 bytes (TCP + IP + Ethernet headers)](http://sd.wareonearth.com/~phil/net/overhead/) + ~20 bytes (your data) = 114 bytes every packet * 30 per second * 15000 users = ~50MBps * 8 bits = ~400Mbps of both incoming and outgoing traffic. Seems you're in troubles here. Consider something wiser than sending your every packet in separate TCP frame. E.g., implement buffer that collects data ready to be sent and is filled by your game logic threads and separate thread that sends this data to network. In this case your several soft packets can be combined into one TCP packet greatly reducing your bandwidth requirements.

But even after this you're still in troubles. I'd recommend to wait for users first before investing into complicated solution. When you'll have them you'll need to implement some kind of clustering. It's separate story, much more complicated than simple networking.

Try to handle at least 1K users by single server. This can bring you some money to hire somebody experienced in game networking/clustering.

Comment: Thanks for that. I want to simulate 1000 clients without the real game client, do you have an idea for that? I already have a server. Linode. I want, as start, to handle 500 users.

Comment: what kink of idea do you look for? just do this, simulate them. Simulation can be very simple (just dummy client that connects to the server, sends valid packets to the server and can receive packets from the server, no moves, no logic) or very complicated - something like full functional client controlled by AI.

Comment: I need very complicated - what is AI?

Comment: @Eli: [Artificial Intelligence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artificial_intelligence_(video_games))

Comment: Thanks. I think I will do just very simple lol, so just run lot of TCP clients?

Answer (score 0):

If you know you sending 30 messages every second, why not bundle them into 1 request, every second? Makes a lot of difference in terms in server resources...

And in which language are you going to run your server? I hope you write something dedicated to process/manage these connections? If so: do some profiling and just measure what you need...
And what is your processor doing every second, to process those 30*15K messages?

There is no generic answer to your question. It all depends on your software.

Comment: Because it's an MMORPG... You see the players that you play with, you can't update the position of other players every 1 second... Server C++. It updates the database unless there is no change, for example the player position.